# How to use dateRangeInput in sqlInterpolate in RShiny

Tags: sql, shiny, date-range

I am trying to output a table that depends on a user selecting a date range in Shiny using sqlInterpolate. Although I have succeeded outputting a table based on a selectInput (dropdown), I can't figure out how to use a dateRangeInput with sqlInterpolate.

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND timestamp BETWEEN '2021-12-15' AND '2021-12-17'' at line 6
```

My approach:

```
pool <- dbPool(
  MariaDB(), 
  db = "db",
  user = user, 
  password = password, 
  host = host, 
  port = port
)

data_pool <- pool %>% tbl("table")

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("daterange"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange2", "Date:", start = "2021-12-15", end = "2021-12-17")
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange2[1], input$daterange2[2])

    sql2 <- "
    SELECT 
      STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AS timestamp
    FROM table
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ?date1 AND ?date2
    "

    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql2, date1 = input$daterange[1], date2 = input$daterange[2])
    dbGetQuery(pool, query)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    data() 
  })
}
```

Comment: You may be missing a semi-colon `;` at the end of SELECT.  Try `sql <- "SELECT...;"`

Comment: I tried the semi-colon, but it wasn't working.